# Error in identify(x, y, labels = name, plot = TRUE)

Tags: r, identify

I trying to use the function identify() on R, but it's not working.
Do you know if there is any package that I'm missing?

It doesn't work not even for a simple code:

```
x = 1:10
y = x^2

name = letters[1:10]    
plot(x, y)
identify(x, y, labels = name, plot=TRUE, n = 2)
```

Comment: Do you get an error message?

Answer (score 1):

This way it works: it is the same code: With `n=2` you have to click on two points:

```
x = 1:10 
y = x^2

name = letters[1:10]
plot(x, y) 
identify(x, y, labels = name, plot=TRUE, n = 2)
```

[image]